# How to Borrow variable multiple times for Logical Operator

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How do we use a variable multiple times as ref for a logical operation? E.g, an OR statement?

```
let check:HashMap<i8, i8> = HashMap::new();
// insert some data into hashmap
if &check.contains_key(1) || &check.contains_key(3) {
    println!("YES!");

}
```

Sorry, new to rust, but trying to learn

Comment: You can borrow twice inside an `||` expression. But `.` has higher precedence than `&`, and thus your expression is parsed as `&(check.contains_key(1)) || &(check.contains_key(3))` While you probably wanted `(&check).contains_key(1) || (&check).contains_key(3)`. Also note that due to autoref, you don't have to take a reference explicitly (`check.contains_key(1) || check.contains_key(3)` will do).

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Do you have a problem? Does your code not compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you're not borrowing what you think you are, but the rules of rust mean you don't need to borrow like you are when calling a method of `HashMap`.  This is simpler, and also I made it mutable so you could insert a value and see success, as well as a query failure.

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut check:HashMap<i8, i8> = HashMap::new();
    // insert some data into hashmap
    check.insert(1, 5);
    // Check for 1 or 3
    if check.contains_key(&1) || check.contains_key(&3) {
        println!("Contained a key of 1 OR 3!");
    }
    if check.contains_key(&3) {
        println!("Contained a key of 3!");
    }
    else
    {
        println!("Did not contain a key of 3!");
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

You don't need to specify `&` or `& mut` before a borrow for a method of a struct.  For the *arguments* yes, but not the method itself, as there is no overloading in Rust (like in C++ or some other languages) and thus it's unambiguous which you call, so Rust does the work borrowing for you.

Link to the online rust playground for [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=99d94f97d0bb628a16703acadfec1272).

Comment: I learned something today. Much better than my answer, +1

Comment: Ah, I see appreciate it!

Comment: "thus it's unambiguous which you call" — actually, there can be multiple possible calls, when traits are implemented for reference types. There is a defined search order, but whether the receiver is a reference *can* affect the outcome.

Comment: [Autoref Specialization](https://lukaskalbertodt.github.io/2019/12/05/generalized-autoref-based-specialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

The input to `contains_key` should be a reference(borrow), and as Chayim said you probably want parenthesis to specify precedence.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn main() {
    let check:HashMap<i8, i8> = HashMap::new();
    // insert some data into hashmap
    if (&check).contains_key(&1) || (&check).contains_key(&3) {
        println!("YES!");
    }
}
```